# PayPal Developer Issues With Comma

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, paypal

I have run into an error. I am using https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integrate/ to implement the PayPal payment into my ASP.NET MVC Project. My currency is a float, and the project has prices like 150,99. Whenever this price goes through, it will say that the price is 99,00 EUR. It only reads what is behind the comma. Whenever the price is 190,00, it will correctly say that the price is 190,00 EUR. How do I fix this?

**The JavaScript on the front-end is currently this:**

```
<script>
    var totalPrice = (@ViewBag.totalPrice);
</script>
<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>
<script>
    // Render the PayPal button
    paypal.Button.render({
        // Set your environment
        env: 'sandbox', // sandbox | production

        // Specify the style of the button
        style: {
            layout: 'horizontal',  // horizontal | vertical
            size: 'large',    // medium | large | responsive
            shape: 'pill',      // pill | rect
            color: 'black'       // gold | blue | silver | white | black
        },

        // Specify allowed and disallowed funding sources
        //
        // Options:
        // - paypal.FUNDING.CARD
        // - paypal.FUNDING.CREDIT
        // - paypal.FUNDING.ELV
        funding: {
            allowed: [
                paypal.FUNDING.CARD,
                paypal.FUNDING.CREDIT
            ],
            disallowed: []
        },

        // Enable Pay Now checkout flow (optional)
        commit: true,

        // PayPal Client IDs - replace with your own
        // Create a PayPal app: https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/create
        client: {
            sandbox: '<removed>',
            production: '<insert production client id>'
        },

        payment: function (data, actions) {
            return actions.payment.create({
                payment: {
                    transactions: [
                        {
                            amount: {
                                total: totalPrice,
                                currency: 'EUR'
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            });
        },

        onAuthorize: function (data, actions) {
            return actions.payment.execute()
                .then(function () {
                    window.alert('Payment Complete!');
                });
        }
    }, '#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

**And back-end for the price is like this:**

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            ...
            float totalPrice = 0;
            float sendcost = 2.95f;
            ...
                        foreach(ShoppingCartModel item in model)
                        {
                            item.subtotal = item.qty * item.price;
                            totalPrice += item.subtotal;
                        }
                        if(totalPrice < 100)
                        {
                            ViewBag.totalPrice = totalPrice + sendcost;;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ViewBag.totalPrice = totalPrice;
                        }
                    }
                }
                ...
        }
```

Comment: In the example code in the docs, all the prices are formatted like `'150.99'`, what's the final output of `var totalPrice = (@ViewBag.totalPrice);`? Have you tried using a period as decimal separator?

Comment: @ChrisG In the JavaScript, I tried the inputs 20.99 and 20,99 at the `total`. And for 20.99 it correctly shows 20,99 EUR on the PayPal Payment view and when I enter 20,99, the payment screen doesn't appear. The final output of `var totalPrice = (@ViewBag.totalPrice);` is any products price, which could be 20,99 or 20,00.

Comment: By final output I mean what the source code looks like in your browser. I'm going to assume it's `var totalPrice = '150,99';` since that's the only way to produce the issue I guess? Anyway, the problem is that English, and consequently all programming languages and APIs, use `.` in their floats. So *if* you end up with `'150,99'`, you just need to `replace()` the comma with a period.

Comment: @ChrisG Doesn't work for me, when I do to do it as `totalPrice = totalPrice.replace("," , ".")` it still gives me back 99,00 EUR in PayPal

Comment: Sorry, I will ask you a third time: what is the final output? What does it say in your browser's source view next to  `var totalPrice = `?

Comment: @ChrisG Oh I'm sorry, I understand your question now. It displays the following: https://imgur.com/a/d2PUskH and when it has 443,00 for example, it displays the following: https://imgur.com/a/YdM5k0A

Comment: Right, that's what's causing this. `(443)` evaluates to `443`, but `(150,99)` evaluates to `99` [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) The quick and dirty fix is `var totalPrice = parseFloat("@ViewBag.totalPrice".replace(",", "."));` but the proper fix is to set up your backend so floating point values are output using a period as decimal separator.

Comment: @ChrisG Yeah the JavaScript solution worked for me, but I'll as you said fix the backend. Thanks a lot for the help man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official answer is that your web app's language setting causes the server to output numerical values with a comma as decimal separator. So

```
var totalPrice = (@ViewBag.totalPrice);
```

ends up

```
var totalPrice = (150,99);
```

in the browser and since JavaScript has something called a [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), `totalPrice` is now `99`.

To fix this on the server side, you can change the locale used for formatting to English by adding

```
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
```

to the `Configure()` method in `Startup.cs`.

Comment: This should work, but it should be noted that changing the culture of all threads in the AppDomain could have other effects that are undesired. Another option is using the [`Single.ToString(string format, IFormatProvider provider)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.single.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Single_ToString_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_) overload that accepts a culture as the second parameter

Comment: Thanks @Stijn for the useful information! It did have some effects on other data in the server side if I tried to change the culture to en-US.